# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet producing 7889 run time error

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to export a table from Access and save it as a simple Excel file. I keep on getting a run time error 7889. Access says the file does not exist.

I checked that I am the only one in the DB. The table is closed (no record locking). I checked to ensure that I have read/write access to the specified path. The file I am producing does not already exist. I have compliled my code and compacted and repaired the database.

```
Dim sPath As String
sPath = "C:\Users\xxxx\MarketMapSourceData_TEST.xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExportDelim, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                            "tbl_3partyCRM", sPath, True
```

I have also tried the following:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tbl_3partyCRM", sPath, True
```

..but this gives me a run time error 3027 object is read only.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I very much doubt that microsoft will let you write to c root.

Comment: sorry. I edited out my user path as I didn't want to show it here. updated to reflect actual path with my user as xxxx. I also changed the error message to 7889

Comment: Can you export manually?

Comment: Exporting manually works fine

Comment: You are mixing up your arguments with a text transfer and an excel transfer, `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "table1", spath, True`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Sometimes it's the simple things... Please post it as the answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up your arguments with a text transfer and an excel transfer

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tablenamehere", spath, True
```